# Change PHP MySQL fetch value into different values for temporary

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im retrieving MySQL data using PHP and Ajax.

I want to echo those using HTML. problem is how to change those value into meaningful values.

in MyTable data store like in 0 or 1. ex:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Member where memberId = '$memberid'";


$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<div class='item1'>
      <h4>"Payment"</h4>
      <p>".$row['payment']."</p></div>";
    }
}else{
    echo "Something Wrong";
}
```

in above its just show the 0 or 1. i want to assign them into

`Payment : 0 or 1 (if 0 , No Payment. If 1, Payment Done)`
how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<p>".$row['payment']."</p></div>";
```

to this:

```
<p>".($row['payment'] == 0 ? "No Payment" : "Payment Done")."</p></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways,
with mysql query like

```
$sql = "SELECT *, IF(payment = 0, 'No Payment', 'Payment Done') as payment FROM Member where memberId = '$memberid'";
```

Or using php

```
$row['payment'] == 0 ? "No Payment" : "Payment Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an answer, but you shouldn't code that way. Coding like that it's almost impossible to create good quality, maintainable code and - in the end - a good piece of software.

You should look around for a framework that will work for you. Choosing framework is a matter of preference in most cases. I can advice you [silex](http://www.slimframework.com/) as it is small, simple, and is a good point to start learning. Start with a simple mvc application for example.

And try to learn using some ORM library, so you can fetch data without writing sql by hand (in most cases) and try to use models and repositories for that.

Or you can do MVC without any framework, if you like. Here's a good tutorial series on [that](https://r.je/mvc-in-php.html). It also include building a routing mechanism, dependency injection and stuff like that.

:edit

In fact i advice you this article series even more, cause it's a better point to gain some "real" understanding what's going on and why when building some serious application, and this tutorial cover the theory also, and looks like it should be easy to follow.

/edit

Good luck :)